# img buttons from json response not working on uiwebview?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, uiwebviewdelegate

Hi how to parse and show the below response from json in a webview using objective c

```html
**Questions==<b font STYLE="color:#006699">Is communication maintained daily through both normal and abnormal conditions?</b><img src="../../../Images/Ops/VV/bulb.jpg" button id='Button1' onclick='return GetChildElement(1);'></button><div class='divHide'><ul type="disc" style="color:#FF0000" ><li>This must be demonstrated and confirmed.</li></ul></div>.**
```

Comment: Please complete your question.

Comment: use XML parser or RegEX for your concept\

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik thanks for quick reply, am really new to ios would you please suggest any tutorial or example for this

Comment: what the content need to load in web view

Comment: description along with img button present in response, when i click on that button again i have to show some sub questions

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik am able to show description in webview but all img buttons are displayed with ? symbol